# YouTube videos to play through JSON

Tags: ios, json

I’m currently in the process of developing an iOS app for a music producer but he wants all his music videos that are on different channels on YouTube for example, SBTV, GRM Daily, RinseFM, Boiler Room etc. But the only way I can think of is through JSON is there a way to put a link in the JSON file or would it have to be done through Xcode/Swift.

I’m open to suggestions and greatful for your responses!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you could do that, the JSON may look something like this (this excerpt is from a Node.js server), then you could play the video with a WKWebView. Here is the official apple documentation, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview

```
var videos = [

{
    name: "Video One", 
    videoURLString: "Youtube.com/whatever",
}, 

{
    name: "Video Two", 
    videoURLString: "Youtube.com/whatever", 
}
];
```

Comment: oh that's awesome!, also in the string you'll be able to include preview of the video thumbnail etc?

Comment: Yes that can be done, this answer may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32691304/ios-how-to-get-thumbnail-from-video-without-play