# Need to show Preview Video Thumbnails while seeking (Like youtube) for iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, video-streaming, video-processing, wowza

I need to show Video Preview Thumbanils while seeking in AVPlayer.
Just like how youtube shows them. **(iOS)**
(Also for live streaming) (Solution preferred more for Wowza/Amazon S3)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS - How to get thumbnail from video without play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32691304/ios-how-to-get-thumbnail-from-video-without-play)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
extension AVAsset {

    func getPreviewImage(for timeInSeconds: Int = 0) -> UIImage? {
        let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: self)
        imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = .zero
        imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = .zero
        imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        guard let cgImage = try? imageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTime(value: CMTimeValue(timeInSeconds), timescale: 1), actualTime: nil) else { return nil }
        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
    }

}
```

You shouldn't get the preview in the main thread.

If you require a series of preview images, you can try [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetimagegenerator/1388100-generatecgimagesasynchronously):

> If you require a series
>   of images, you can achieve far greater efficiency using the
>   asynchronous method,
>   generateCGImagesAsynchronously(forTimes:completionHandler:), which
>   employs decoding efficiencies similar to those used during playback.

Comment: The thing is this approach doesn't provide me smooth scrolling or on the go thumbnail display. (It takes a bit to get the particular thumbnail at a particular time)

Comment: @RajPahelajani Do you get the preview in a background thread?

Comment: I tried that but it's not what I expect, Also for the videos with extension 'm3u8' this approach doesn't provide me the thumbnails.

Comment: @RajPahelajani I see an edited post. Maybe it's because of the live streaming, I don’t know. I use this for regular videos.

Comment: @RajPahelajani I updated my answer.

For greater efficiency, you can try `generateCGImagesAsynchronously`.

I have not found out yet why this does not work with the extension "m3u8".

Comment: You should try getting thumbnai from thread other than main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Youtube helper instead -
https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper

Comment: This is only for playing youtube videos and not other videos and live streams.